# Unable to include interactive python shell in flask app for GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am using flask and the python 2.7 GAE SDK. I am trying to include an interactive shell, in my app.

I am trying to include the following interactive python shell in my app, so that I can interact with the GAE API while development - http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/shell/

As instructed I have copied the static/ and templates/ folders, and shell.py to the root of my app.

I have also added the url route ONLY to my app.yaml (shell)-

```
application: myflaskonappengineapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

default_expiration: "5d"

builtins:
- appstats: on
- admin_redirect: on
- deferred: on
- remote_api: on

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3"
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.3"
- name: setuptools
  version: "0.6c11"
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.3"
- name: webob
  version: "1.1.1"
- name: yaml
  version: "3.10"

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: application/static/img/favicon.ico
  upload: application/static/img/favicon.ico

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: application/static/robots.txt
  upload: application/static/robots.txt

- url: /_gae_mini_profiler/static
  static_dir: packages/flaskext/gae_mini_profiler/static

- url: /static
  static_dir: application/static

#interactive shell
- url: /shell
  script: shell.py

- url: /remote_api
  script: /opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py

- url: .*
  script: application.app
```

However when I try to access the url /shell, I get a 404 error ? Do I need to configure flask also for routing ? Why is flask handling this url instead of shell.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the shell.py to handle the URL '/shell' as well as app.yaml.
In particular, you need to edit [the line 303 of the shell.py](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/shell/shell.py#303).

from

```
    [('/', FrontPageHandler),
```

to

```
    [('/shell', FrontPageHandler),
```

You also need to update your app.yaml like(add wildcard):

```
- url: /shell.*
  script: shell.py
```

Please consider adding login:admin to the shell handler, otherwise you will open up the shell capability to everyone in the world.